# Creating additional date rows for non existent data (Redshift SQL)

Tags: sql, date, group-by, sum, amazon-redshift

I am looking at agent data and want to create an overview of their sales performance within the last 6 months. I have cases where agents just started, some started 3 months ago, but I want to create a view, where there alsways be 6 rows for each agent, no matter when she/he started, there just won't be any sales listed in these rows. This view is importat, because I want to have the option to average the values and show different granularities at some point (agent level, team level etc..)
I am working with Redshift SQL and have the agent data. That is my query:

```
select date, id, name, team, country, sum(sales) 
from agent 
where date >= date_trunc('month', dateadd(month, -6, current_date) and date <= current_date
group by 1,2,3,4,5 
order by 1
```

Which gives me the output below (without the green rows), how could I add additional rows/months for Roman, an agen that started in February. Any ideas, suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all dates are available in the table (as shown in your sample data), one option is to `cross join` the available dates with the list of agents to generate all possible combinations, then bring the original table with a `left join`:

```
select d.date, n.id, n.name, n.team, n.country, sum(a.sales) 
from (select distinct date from agent) d
cross join (select distinct id, name, team, country from agent) n
left join agent a on a.date = d.date and a.id = n.id
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
order by 1, 2
```

This assumes that `id` uniquely identies an agent; otherwise, you would need additional join conditions in the `left join` (on `name`, `team`, `country`).

Comment: To restrict it to the past 7 month, does the date addition make sense? ```select d.date, n.id, n.name, n.team, n.country, sum(a.sales) 
from (select distinct date from agent where date >= date_trunc('month', dateadd(month, -6, current_date) and date <= current_date) d
cross join (select distinct id, name, team, country from agent) n
left join agent a on a.date = d.date and a.id = n.id
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 
order by 1, 2```

Comment: @kris030: yes, that makes sense.